# Angular2 call a Component from a Service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to call a Method in my `Component` from a a `Service`. What is the proper way to do this? I have tried to use `rxjs Subject` to create an Observable, but I cannot get it to fire.

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
    export class MyService {
        callComponent = function(value) {

            let invokeEvent = new Subject();

            invokeEvent.next({some:value})
        }
    }
```

and in my Component

```
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
             this._myService.invokeEvent.subscribe(value => console.log(value))
           }

}
```

Comment: I can't draw the relationship between the temporary variable `invokeEvent` in your service and the object `this._myService.invokeViewEvent` that you are using in the component.

Comment: sorry typo. It is the invokeEvent that I am trying to listen for. When I call `callComponent` I want to get the Component to fire. I am stuck on observables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WKSurRJMXo5JZOPrwSP5?p=preview

Change your service like this

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    invokeEvent:Subject<any> = new Subject();


    callComponent(value) {
        this.invokeEvent.next({some:value})
    }
}
```

Don't forget to provide it in your component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
  `,
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyComponent {
       constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
         this._myService.invokeEvent.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
         setTimeout(()=>{
            this._myService.callComponent(1);
         },1000);
       }
}
```

Also, If you want this service to be a global shared service; put(provide) it in your bootstrap(old) or ngModule so it will share the same singleton instance throughout your app.

Comment: Some additional information is that I have exposed my service method to window, outside of angular2 app. So that I can call it like `window.myangular.MyService.callComponent()` I have tried wrapping in zone.run and detechChanges() already. I can see that the call is succesful from consoles in the method.

Comment: @Rob I've updated my answer with a plunker sir. I'm erasing my previous comments.

Comment: That did it! The issue was that it didnt like having `MyService` in the `Component` `providers:[ ]`. It required it to be in primary app module only. Strange to me, but thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rob You should not use` setTimout` for this.

Comment: @micronyks why not?

Comment: @echonax why you want to delay it for 1sec even when you can get immediate value once value is omitted.You should not use `setTimeout` instead you can use it with `asObservable()` as shown in my answer.

Comment: @micronyks I wanted to value change to be observed with the eye in the view rather than seeing it immediately

Comment: @echonax you can do it even with `asObservable`. `setTimout` is not recommended to use.

Comment: I dont have setTimeout in my code. I assumed it was for demonstrating.

Answer (score 1):

you can define `Observable` in service so that you can subscribe to that Observable from component.

//service

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private notify = new Subject<any>();
  /**
   * Observable string streams
   */
  notifyObservable$ = this.notify.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  public notifyOther(data: any) {
    if (data) {
      this.notify.next(data);
    }
  }

  callComponent(value){
    this.notify.next({some:value});
  }
}
```

//Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { MyService } from './my.service';
export class MyComponent {
  private subscription: Subscription;
  constructor( private _myService: MyService ){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._myService.notifyObservable$.subscribe((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot get this to work. I structured my code to match this and still no go.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class MyService {

        private invokeEvent = new Subject(); 

        invokeEvent$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();   //<<< this is important to declare invokeEvent with asObservable(); 

        callComponent = function(value) {
            invokeEvent.next({some:value})
        }
}


export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
             this._myService
                 .invokeEvent$                                        //<<< subscribe to invokeEvent$ to get the result
                 .subscribe(value => console.log(value))  
           }

}
```